# Selenium Python not able to extract [object Text] It should be an element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am new to Selenium and I have been having a problem, I am trying to extract the the title "ferric maltol" as string, here:

https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=C062088

But I have been having lots of troubles with this.

Using the xpath in Python with several different attempts, but none work:

1. First attempt

```
to_store=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/h1/text()').get_attribute('textContent')
```

> *** selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/div[2]/h1/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

2. Second attempt

```
to_store=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/h1/text()').text
```

> *** selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/div[2]/h1/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

3. Third attempt

```
to_store=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/h1/text()').get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/div[2]/h1/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Do see my answer and let me know if it helps.

Comment: In this particular case even `//h1` xpath selector should work: `to_store=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1").text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium won't allow you to locate an element using Text node. As an alternative you can use below javascript code to extract text

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h1.ng-binding.ng-scope')
text = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].textContent", element);
print(text.strip())
```

**Output:**

> ferric maltol

Comment: Thaaanks soo much! It fit like a glooove! I have to learn Java! It looks really handy! Thanks again i was pretty hopeless

Answer (score 2):

As your XPath expression terminates with text(), this resolves to a text container, and not an HTML element (or list of). You therefore, get the above error.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver.exe') #set your path here
driver.get("https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=C062088")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(45)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
SpecialPrice=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/dl/dd[1]").text
print(SpecialPrice)
```

Outputs

```
ferric maltol
```

Using the above method you pass in the full `xpath` and use the `text` attribute to get the value.

Comment: Uoooooou! I see my mistake! thaanks so muuch! It worked really well, I also did not thought i would need a timeout and a wait. Thaaaanks it really helped!

Comment: Same issue for me. I am trying to get "Snowden-Pencer"    from https://accessgudid.nlm.nih.gov/devices/10885403151217. Can you help with the xPath here?

Comment: i need to see your code and see where you are going wrong. I would recommend asking it as a question and reply the link here so i can take a look at it.